# Doing sophisticated image analysis with python / django

Tags: django, image-processing, image-manipulation, document

I am working on a django project that analyzes images that contain text and (1) infers if the image needs to be rotated and (2) where text areas are.

I am currently using PIL to do some more simpler processing of these images but I am not quite sure how I can use PIL or other libraries to perform both tasks. I was wondering if anyone has done this before and if there are libraries / api available to help in the development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV is probably the post popular open source image processing library. It's C/C++ but there are python bindings:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

and the python docs

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html

I've never done an OCR with it, but I'm sure it's capable

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pastylegs that OpenCV is your best initial bet. If you need stuff specific to OCR you could also look at [ocropus](https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/).